# Expressing formula within a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this existing query:

```
SELECT 
  extension
, Total_Outbound+Total_Missed+Total_Received AS Total_Calls
, Total_Missed
, Total_Talk_Time_minutes    
FROM (
  SELECT 
, extension       
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
, sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Received
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes

  FROM session a
  GROUP BY extension 
 ) x;
```

It works great but I need to add a metric/formula to it called `missed_call_score` right under `Total_Talk_Time_Minutes`.

The formula for the missed call score is this:
`(missed calls/total talk time) * (average calls per CSR/total calls) * 100` but one thing to note is that the `average calls per csr` needs to ignore the MAX and MIN, so the lowest and highest number of calls taken.

I'm not sure how I could construct this score within a single select variable or the syntax I would use for this given the fact that it has to throw out the max and min.

Here is an example of my needed output and the formulas it should be using:

```
extension | Total calls | missed calls | total talk time | missed call score
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234            8               4               15.5            5.7
4321            4               0               9.42            0.0
5678            5               2               6.78            6.5
9876            13              6               18.3            7.2


Total call sum = 30
Total call sum without high and low = 13
average calls per CSR = (13/2) = 6.5

extension 1 = (4/15.5) * (6.5/30) * 100 = 5.7
extension 2 = (0/9.42) * (6.5/30) * 100 = 0.0
extension 3 = (2/6.78) * (6.5/30) * 100 = 6.5
extension 4 = (6/18.3) * (6.5/30) * 100 = 7.2
```

The data above for extension, total calls, missed calls and talk time are taken from my sql fiddle, linked below. I simply added the score column to give example of my expected output.

The fiddle linked below shows my create and inserts so hopefully that gives everything needed to assist me with this.

**sql fiddle
**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1f9/1

**UPDATE**

Full production query with joins

```
 SELECT    firstn , 
             lastn , 
             extension , 
             Total_Outbound+Total_Missed+Total_Received AS Total_Calls , 
             Total_Missed , 
             Total_Talk_Time_minutes , 
             Total_All_Calls , 
             Max_Calls , 
             Min_Calls , 
             CSR_Count , 
             ((Total_Missed/Total_Talk_Time_minutes) *  
             (((Total_All_Calls-Max_Calls-Min_Calls)/CSR_Count)/Total_All_Calls)) * 100 
             FROM (   SELECT     u.firstn     , 
             u.lastn     , 
             c.extension        , 
             sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed , 
             sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Received , 
             sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Outbound ,
             round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes , 

             (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ambition.session a INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID    
             INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID       
             INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension  
             WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()       
             AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)) Total_All_Calls , 

             (SELECT MAX(CNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, c.extension 
             FROM ambition.SESSION a INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID       
             INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID      
             INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension 
             WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()       
             AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312) GROUP BY responsibleuserextensionid) y) Max_Calls , 

             (SELECT MIN(CNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, c.extension
             FROM ambition.SESSION a 
             INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID       
             INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID       
             INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension   
             WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()       
             AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)GROUP BY responsibleuserextensionid) y) Min_Calls , 

             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.extension)-2 
             FROM ambition.SESSION a INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID       
             INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID       
             INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension  
             WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()       
             AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)) CSR_Count       

             FROM ambition.session a       
             INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID       
             INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID       
             INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension       
             LEFT JOIN ambition.knownnumbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number       
             WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()       
             AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)       
             GROUP BY c.extension, u.firstn, u.lastn    ) x
```

Comment: What if there was more than one instance of the max (or min) `Total_Calls` value?  Would you ignore all of them or just one instance when determining your average?

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand, but I have 15 CSRs taking calls daily. Usually one is training or doing something where they take hardly any calls in a day and the other takes about 50-60 more calls than the others daily, so there is always a VERY low and VERY high number so I just want my formula to always take that into account

Comment: A common way to filter this would be to remove records from consideration where value = max(value)... but if many CSRs happened to have the max(value), then it would ruin the formula.  It sounds like that is very unlikely to ever happen but I avoided the possibility in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT 
  extension
, Total_Outbound+Total_Missed+Total_Received AS Total_Calls
, Total_Missed
, Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, Total_All_Calls
, Max_Calls
, Min_Calls
, CSR_Count
, ((Total_Missed/Total_Talk_Time_minutes) * 
      (((Total_All_Calls-Max_Calls-Min_Calls)/CSR_Count)/Total_All_Calls)) * 100
FROM (
  SELECT 
 extension       
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
, sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Received
, sum(CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Outbound
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM session) Total_All_Calls
, (SELECT MAX(CNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, EXTENSION FROM SESSION GROUP BY EXTENSION) y) Max_Calls
, (SELECT MIN(CNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, EXTENSION FROM SESSION GROUP BY EXTENSION) y) Min_Calls
, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EXTENSION)-2 FROM SESSION) CSR_Count

  FROM session a
  GROUP BY extension 
 ) x;
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1f9/35/0).

Basically I used sub-counts in your derived table `x` to get each of the variables needed for `missed_call_score`.  One major thing worth noting is that the logic was off for `Total_Outbound`, so I tweaked that to a `CASE` statement instead of an `IF()`.  I selected the count columns in the outer query just so you can see what is going on, you can remove those.

Comment: This looks pretty perfect! I I'm currently doing this for testing but If i modify this for production, where my tables are joined  then how would I modify the max and min lines? Join for production query: ```FROM ambition.session a
      INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
      INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension
      LEFT JOIN ambition.knownnumbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
      GROUP BY c.extension```

Comment: To clarify, the only change in that instance is that ```extension``` is joined and coming from another table, so the extensions won't be explicitly placed in the session table. But the fiddle is doing exactly what I needed, thank you! I'm just seeing how I might slightly modify that for the production case where the tables are joined instead of everything in one table.

Comment: @TomN. Hmm it's really hard to answer that without really knowing the schema, but looking at the joins, I think you could keep `Total_All_Calls` as it is, and replace the `extension` column with `responsibleuserextensionid` in the `min/max` subqueries.  The main risk that is unknown to me is if those `INNER JOIN`s are removing records from the result set, then you may need them in each subquery too (or the counts will be wrong).

Comment: Ideally, you can keep the subqueries to only the `session` table because it will be much more efficient than doing the multiple joins repeatedly.  But it all depends on if you get the results you want. :P

Comment: It looks like that will work, thanks! The only thing I'll have to change is to apply a where clause to those so that it only counts extensions from my 15 CSRs. Actually, I'm running into an issue with that but I'll probably need to create a new question for that in particular

Comment: So just to be safe, could I apply all of my joins to the three subqueries as well?

Comment: I updated my question with the full query. I pasted the inner joins to each subquery and it seems to work except the total calls and max calls are off slightly from my existing Total_calls field

Comment: @TomN. Looks good, you just need to change this `sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Outbound` to what I have above: `sum(CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Outbound`

Comment: Without the `ANSWERED = 1` it is including missed calls in the outgoing calls count.  Either that or `Missed_Calls` is including some dialed calls in the count.  I noticed this because in your example, there are 24 total records in `session`, but you were getting `30 total calls` with your original logic.

Comment: Cool thanks again, and I did make that change as well. I know all the joins make it messy and possibly expensive with time to complete, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past and extracted this snippet from my code.

I think/hope that this might help you getting started (I left out most of the columns from your query and you'd have to adjust avg(amount) to match your formula.

```
select extension, avg(amount) from 
(
select t.*, 
min(amount) over (partition by extension) as min_amt, 
max(amount) over (partition by extension) as max_amt 
from your_table t
) t
where amount > min_amt and amount < max_amt group by extension;
```

Comment: I'm trying to modify this but Is this sql server syntax? Or something else? I'm using mysql workbench and can't seem to get the syntax right